# Send struct with char[] in MPI

Tags: c++, c, struct, char, mpi

I'm trying to send some data from workers to a master (ranked 0) in a MPI program in C++. The goal is to pass 2 strings and an integer. To do that, I've created a struct.

**The struct**

It is called *word* and defined as follows:

```
struct word
{
    char word_name[str_size];
    char url[str_size];
    int counter;
};

/* Some important variables to the question */

MPI_Datatype mpi_word_type;
const int str_size = 200;
```

Previously I was trying this through `char *` but it doesn't work, since the processes don't share the same memory space.

By now, I'm able to send the struct if I change the variables from `char[]` to a simple `char` and try with an example. With this as it is above, I cannot get rid of *Segmentation fault* errors.

**Sending Part - Workers**

I start by creating and filling an example struct and then sending the size of the struct first and the struct itself, secondly. Like this:

```
word word_col;
std::string tmp = "somename";
strcpy(word_col.word_name, tmp.c_str());

std::string tmp2 = "someurl";
strcpy(word_col.url, tmp2.c_str());

word_col.counter = 10;

int size = sizeof(word_col);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&size, 1, MPI::INT, 0, 1);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&word_col, size, mpi_word_type, 0, 1);
```

**Receiving Part - Master**

```
const int nitems = 3;
int blocklengths[3] = { str_size, str_size, 1 };
MPI_Datatype types[3] = { MPI::CHAR, MPI::CHAR, MPI::INT };
MPI_Aint offsets[3];

offsets[0] = (MPI_Aint) offsetof(struct word, word_name);
offsets[1] = (MPI_Aint) offsetof(struct word, url);
offsets[2] = (MPI_Aint) offsetof(struct word, counter);

MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_word_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_word_type);

...

for(...)
{
    word word_col;
    int size;

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&size, 1, MPI::INT, MPI::ANY_TAG, 1, status);
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&word_col, size, mpi_word_type, MPI::ANY_TAG, 1, status);
}
```

I've been struggling with this for hours and I've seen many examples and another questions about this, but I couldn't figure out what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This is erroneous programming. You have unallocated and uninitialized pointer and you are trying to push data to that.
You have two options:
Either you define your structure as:

```
const int str_size = 200;
struct word
{
    char word_name[str_size]; // fixed sized char array
    char url[str_size]; // fixed sized char array
    int counter;
};
```

Or,

```
const int str_size = 200;
struct word
{
    char *word_name; /
    char *url;
    int counter;
    Word() {
      word_name = new char[str_size];
      url = new char[str_size];
    }
    ~Word() {
      delete [] word_name;
      delete [] url;
    }
};
```

The idea is that you need to have allocated memory for these variables
Also, while receiving, you have used:

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&word_col, size, mpi_word_type, MPI::ANY_TAG, 1, status);
```

Shouldn't it be like below?

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&word_col, sizeof(word_col), mpi_word_type, MPI::ANY_TAG, 1, status);
```

Comment: My previous struct in the question had an error. I'd been trying some things and that's the reason. I've corrected it to have `[str_size]`. But it doesn't work like this.

Comment: @gd.silva, so one part you already corrected, check if you are passing correct size while receiving, check my edited ans

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the correct size. The variable `size` is the same as `sizeof(word_col)`, because I do that `sizeof` before I send it.

Comment: @DebasishJana you can skip the "is risky and" part in your answer. It's not "risky and erroneous programming" it's just "erroneous programming".